# What is the exact difference between "Connect timed out" and "failed to connect to" in java.net.SocketTimeoutException?

Tags: java, android, sockets, http, exception

In my log, I could find two SocketTimeoutException.

**1. SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out**

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out  
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345) 
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)  
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)   
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) 
...
```

**2. SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to..**

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to somedomain.com/123.123.123.44 (port 80) after 30000ms
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:169)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:122)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:456)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:882)
...
```

What are the differences between **connect timed out** and **failed to connect to** ?

Comment: I would say there is no difference at all, just a rather non-standard implementation in the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The words mean the same thing, so my take is that the exceptions are indicating the same thing.

The different messages are due to two different socket implementations being used.

- The first case is using the standard Java plain (non-SSL) socket implementation; i.e. the default one on Java SE.
- The second case is using the IOBridge implementation that is used on Android.

It seems that some of your logs are coming from Android devices.

Comment: Yeah, Both exceptions are made from android devices.